# What is the difference between JavaScript Object creation methods?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I've been trying to learn OOP in Javascript more deeply.There're different ways of creating class and objects in JavaScript. If I understood correctly, two most popular ways are the ones below. But the thing I don't understand what is the different between them. The methods are giving **exactly** the same result. If they are identical then why there are two different ways?

V1

```
function Country(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.cities=[];
    this.continent;
}

Country.prototype={
    constructor:Country,
    addCity:function(name){
        this.cities.push(name)
    },
    setContinent:function(continent){
        this.continent=continent;
    }
}
```

V2

```
function Country(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.cities=[];
    this.continent;

    this.addCity=function(name){
        this.cities.push(name);
    }

    this.setContinent=function(continent){
        this.continent=continent;
    }
}
```

Thank your four great answers. I understood the difference correctly. Probably you know, it's been possible to create class and objects like in Java as of EcmaScript6.

**Addition**

Then this system is identical to prototype method and there is no drawback to use.

```
class Country
{

    constructor(name){
        this.name=name;
        this.cities=[];
        this.continent;
    }

    addCity(name){
        this.cities.push(name);
    }

    setContinent(continent){
        this.continent=continent;
    }
}

c1 = new Country()
c2 = new Country()
console.log(c1.addCity == c2.addCity) // gives true
```

I've tried @vothaison's method and like I said I guess this is the same as the prototype method.

Comment: MDN uses the first approach: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @charty Although your ES6 class looks like your V2, internal it is more like V1.

Comment: I think I don't need to update the answer. This is an excellent explanation: https://reinteractive.com/posts/235-es6-classes-and-javascript-prototypes ; Please check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two ways are not the same, and V1 is the way to go.

With V1, all new instances of Country created will use the same innstace of addCity method and setContinent method.

Whereas in V2, all instances have their own instance of addCity method and setContinent method, which is a waste of resource.

You test them with this code:

```
c1 = new Country()
c2 = new Country()
c1.addCity == c2.addCity // true in V1, false in V2
```

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

V1 is the recommended way to go.

It uses the [Prototype Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/prototype-design-pattern)

> The Prototype Pattern creates new objects, but rather than creating non-initialized objects it returns objects that are initialized with values it copied from a prototype - or sample - object. The Prototype pattern is also referred to as the Properties pattern.

MDN explains the pros and cons very well: [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)